# The myth of 7±2 options: more recent research?

Tags: choices

So, I am well aware that it's not true that in menu's etc. one should show only 7±2 options, because the [original research by Miller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Magical_Number_Seven,_Plus_or_Minus_Two) was about [working memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_memory). However this does not necessarily mean that more is better (though in some cases it might), given too many options it does become harder to choose and choices that are too complex will be postponed or even skipped. Thus my question is: has there been any research done as to what the optimal number of choices is when a user is actively comparing the various options?

And to give a concrete case to discuss:

> There are 200 products of a certain type. The user wants to buy one product of that type. The system knows which products are best and worst (put differently, the 200 products are sorted by likelihood that the user will want to buy them). How many products should the system actively present to the user to maximize sales?

The thing is just that in a case where a user is bound to make a choice I don't see any downside to showing more choices (except a worse UX), but in cases where a user already is in a stable state: for example when he already has a mobile phone subscription and is vaguely interested in switching giving too many choices can easily lead the user to postponing the choice to another time.

Comment: So you want to know how many items to show at a time? Or you want to know how many items a user can have in working memory? Personally I think the number of items to show is irrelevant, since the buyers interest is only around the items she/he is interested in. Or do I miss your question completely?

Comment: @BennySkogberg I don't (really) care about working memory (directly), that's why I disregarded Millers research. The user technically cares about all 200 hypotetical items, but nobody wants to go through for example 200 different mobile phone subscriptions and showing 200 different mobile phone subscriptions would quite definitely intimidate a user (even disregarding the entire part where he just gives up when presented with too many choices after starting).

Comment: This isn't new, but still very valid research that essentially says it's not the amount of navigation, but that the navigation helps the person get to the next place: http://www.uie.com/reports/scent_of_information/

Comment: And it doesn't seem like your issue is the number of items, but how a person can sort through them. You are correct, no one wants to sort through 200 items, so the goal is to figure out how a person would want to sift through them all. Consider faceted search.

Comment: @DA01 Nah, faceted search is exactly the evil I want to prevent. It's great for 'geeks' like you and me, but it's an incredibly intimidating interface and mentality for the average user. Oh well, in the end I will be going with around 7 items and then do some practical user testing later on.

Comment: @DavidMulder I disagree. Amazon uses it. My mom uses Amazon. But it doesn't literally have to be faceted search, either. Just a way to categorize or group the results so it's not a long list of 200 products.

Comment: @DA01 Faceted search works fine in cases where you know exactly what you are searching for, but it's not without reason that amazon has [these quiz thingies](http://www.amazon.com/Notebooks-Laptop-Computers/b?node=565108) to fill in the faceted search for you often.

Comment: @DavidMulder again, don't get hung up on that specific term. The issue is grouping and categorization. However you do it. The problem you have isn't related at all to the 7/2 theory (be it somewhat correct in terms of memory retention or the incorrect correlation to navigation). The problem you have is simply figuring out how to enable a person to browser through 200 products.

Comment: So, actually, as such, I'd suggest maybe rewording this question--or splitting it into two questions, given the example isn't really related to the 7/2 theory.

Answer (score 1):

Your example seems to ask the age-old question: is the [Paradox of Choice](http://freakonomics.com/2009/12/02/is-the-paradox-of-choice-not-so-paradoxical-after-all/) is actually real?

What we do know is that, whether it is real or not, there *are* still better and worse ways to show lots of information. Images in grids are better than lists (evidence: [Academic study summarised by Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overchoice#cite_ref-Townsend_11-1) and [Neilsen UX research](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/image-vs-list-mobile-navigation/).)

While the jury may still be out on the paradox, there are certainly some field examples:

- Sheena S. Iyengar's jam display showed (not empirically) that 6 jams were better than 24
- Apple has decided that two iPhones convert better (online) than all the Samsungs
- Fashion stores typically only show 25 items per page

In conclusion: either even the brightest minds in UX don't know, or it seems like it entirely depends on the situation/product/item.

Comment: To add to your list, Trader Joes did extensive research and determined that fewer choices in food was a much better user experience (for example, 2 types of peanut butter vs. 30)